# D3 - 2 different bar paddings

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/avVtvdm8Q8tnClAqYxlH?p=preview

Its a bar chart showing two diiferent data points on each point of the x axis.

The bars have the same padding set in the xscale

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(.33)
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { 
    return d.phase
  }));
```

Id like the green bars to have more padding and so be inside the red bars

How can I set different padding on the green bars.

Comment: I'm partly there but now I need to centre the green bars - https://plnkr.co/edit/avVtvdm8Q8tnClAqYxlH?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two different approaches I can think of right away:

1. Set an offset to define how much less should the inner bar width should be compared to the outer and adjust the bars accordingly.

   ```
   var offset = 10;
   chart.selectAll(".bar").attr("x", (d, i) => {
     return i%2 ? x(d.phase)+offset/2 : x(d.phase)
   })
   .attr("y", (d, i) => {
      return y(d.finish);
    })
   .attr("width", (d,i) => {
      return i%2 ? x.bandwidth()-offset : x.bandwidth();
   })
   ```

   **Plunkr:** https://plnkr.co/edit/2ZSKGmjj3ntJEA3KGq9e?p=preview
2. Set a different scale for the green bars (I'd prefer this approach):

   ```
   var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(.56)
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { 
      return d.phase
   }));
   ```

   And accordingly, change the bar attributes:

   ```
   chart.selectAll(".bar")
     .attr("x", (d, i) => {
       return i % 2 ? x(d.phase)+(Math.abs(x1.bandwidth()-x.bandwidth())/2) : x(d.phase)
     })
     .attr("y", (d, i) => {
       return y(d.finish);
     })

     .attr("width", (d, i) => {
       return i % 2 ? x1.bandwidth() : x.bandwidth()
     })
   ```

   The tricky part here would be setting the inner bar offset but you can clearly see the logic there:
   **Difference between the bandwidths of the scales/2**

   **Plunkr:**https://plnkr.co/edit/X5vFB99JBHkfGvSIfXAo?p=preview

Hope this helps.